# Is it possible to change the value of "Created By" in Comments list of a blog?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint blog where few people can contribute but everyone can comment. But they want to comment as anonymous. So I created a new column in Comments list called "Post as anonymous" with a check box value (Boolean value). Now, based on the check box value I want to change the "Created by" to "Anonymous" in Comments web part so that people cannot see the real commenter.

I tried to accomplish this by designing a Workflow in SP designer. But it turns out that there is no "Created By" in "Set field as" action.

Is there any way to accomplish commenting anonymously? **without a third party application.**

Comment: I guess you need to create a custom Visual Web Part same as Commenting Web Part and then if Anonymous is checked... You should use [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) to insert the comment in Comments list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no way to do what you want in a true sense. If people are logged in, Created By will always contain their name, and you can't change it.

What you can do, though, is use a DVWP that hides the value if the box is checked. Just keep in mind that anyone who is smart enough to know where the Comments list is can see the real value.

Comment: I think this solution will work. Because I will be the single admin and I can hide the comments list access from other users....